# Need to add line numbers extreme left of the page

Tags: line-numbering

I need to add line number in the latex `{revtex4-1}` generated pdf file. I am using the userpakage `\usepackage{lineno}` and `\linenumbers` after `\begin{document}`.
It's showing the line number but very close to the text file.

I want the line number in the extreme left of the page. Can someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you add a complete minimal document showing the problem.

Comment: You can try something like `\setlength\linenumbersep{1cm}` to adjust the space between the line numbers and the text.

Answer (score 3):

Change `\linenumbersep` to be 1in plus `\oddsidemargin`, but then subtract the width of the box reserved for the numbers, that is, `\linenumberwidth`.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lineno}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\linenumbers

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\linenumbersep}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in-\linenumberwidth\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot egreg. It's really work the exact way I wanted. Thanks again.